# Cannot find module './merge'

Tags: node.js

The below is what's in my current file(s). Being absolutely new to this field understanding documentation is key. However, I can't see what i missed as to why the "Module Not Found" error would be thrown. What am I missing?

my server.js code file:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()
const multer = require('multer')
const {mergedPdf} = require ('./merge')

const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });
app.use("/static", express.static('public'));
const port = 3000;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "templates/index.html"));
});

app.post('/merge', upload.array('pdfs', 2), async (req, res, next)=> {
  console.log(req.files)
  let d = await mergePdfs(path.join(__dirname, req.files[0].path), path.join(__dirname, req.files[1].path))
  res.redirect(`http://localhost:3000/static/${d}.pdf` )
  // res.send({data: req.files})
  // req.files is array of `photos` files
  // req.body will contain the text fields, if there were any
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

I also installed $npm install request

Comment: Do you have a merge.js next to server.js?

Answer (score 0):

You don't find the module `merge` because the file `merge.js`, in your case due to the `./merge`, must be located in the same directory as your file `server.js`. Furthermore, in your case, the file `merge.js` must contain the function `mergedPdf`

```js
module.exports = { mergedPdf }

function mergedPdf (...) {...}
```